# función que valida numeros y espacios vacios

Tags: javascript, html5

saben tengo un problema con una función en JavaScript, les dejo el código para que vean lo que tengo:

```
function SoloNumeros(e){

var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;

        if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))

        return true;

        return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}
```

Bueno resulta que tal y como indica el nombre de la función, esta me válida que el usuario solamente ingrese números, pero no me deja ingresar espacios, si me pudieran dar una sugerencia de qué y dónde debo modificar mi código para que además de validar el ingreso de números permita ingresar espacios.

Nota: Ya intenté usar un código que aparece en esta página web:
https://efunctions.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/expresiones-regulares-en-javascript/

El cual es el siguiente:

```
function validaSoloNumerico(cadena){

var patron = /^\d*$/;

if (!cadena.search(patron))

    return true;

    else{

    return false;
        }
}
```

Incorporé la dirección relacionada al archivo js en el comienzo de mi pagina en html y en el "input" correspondiente añadí la propiedad onkeypress que retornaba la función y aun así no me funcionó solamente me funciona el primer código que mencioné más arriba. Bueno si me pueden ayudar, se los agradecería mucho. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Qué es un "espacio vacio" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Te recomiendo que "trates" de entender que hace el código antes de realizar el "copia y pega"

---

La variable `keynum` almacena el código del carácter Unicode de la tecla que activa el evento `onkeypress`.

```
var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
```

Es lo mismo que el siguiente código, el cual se usa por incompatibilidad de propiedades entre los diferentes exploradores.

```
var keynum = e.which || e.keyCode;
```

Luego, cuando evaluas `(keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46)` estás permitiendo que se active las teclas <kbd>8:backspace (Retroceso)</kbd> o <kbd>46: full stop (punto)</kbd>. Para permitir la tecla <kbd>32:space (Espacio)</kbd> es incluir el número 32.

```js
function SoloNumeros(e){
  var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
  console.log(e.which || e.keyCode);

  if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46) || (keynum == 32))
    return true;

  return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return SoloNumeros(event)" />
```

*PD. No olvidar comentar en `console.log`.*

---

**Referencia:**

- [HTML Unicode](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp)
- [Propiedad KeyboardEvent which](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_which.asp)
- [Propiedad KeyboardEvent keyCode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a la segunda función que has puesto, para validar con expresiones regulares números y espacios deberías usar otra expresión, ya que la que pones sólo te va a validar números.

- `\d` coincide con un carácter de número
- `\s` coincide con carácteres de espaciado
- `^` y `$` son el principio y el final de la expresión respectivamente

Si usas este último, debes indicar un número de caracteres que puedan coincidir, si no exclusivamente la expresión regular dará por válido un sólo caracter numérico o espaciado.

La expresión podría ser `/^[\d\s]{1,60}$/`

[Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Además, para evaluar una expresión regular, puedes usar el método `test()`

[Método test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test)

```js
//Expresion regular
var patron = /^([\d\s]{1,60})$/

function validaSoloNumerico() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

  if (patron.test(input)) {
    console.log('verdadero');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('false');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="input">
<button onclick="validaSoloNumerico();">Valida</button>
```

Como te han dicho en el comentario anterior, es recomendable que trates de entender el código antes de usarlo.